# Terraform - Resource doesn't not have attribute 'id when using slice function

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I'm using output from one module to pass it to another:

```
output "subnets_id_wan" {
  value       = "${azurerm_subnet.wan.*.id}"
    depends_on = [
    "azurerm_subnet.wan",
  ]
}
```

In output i'm getting

```
 security_groups_id_wan = [
    /subscriptions/111-222-333-4445/resourceGroups/default_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/DF-DTAP-WAN-Subnet-Security-Group
    ]
```

i'm passing this output to network interface resource

```
#Create network interface

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "public_ip" {

  count = "${var.enable_public_ip ? 1 : 0}"
  provider                  = "azurerm.base"
  name                      = "Network_Inteface_Public_IP_${var.env_name}_${var.azure_instance_names}"
  location                  = "${module.azure_vnet_dtap.resource_group_location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${module.azure_vnet_dtap.resource_group_name}"
  network_security_group_id = "${var.enable_security_group ? element(concat(azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.*.id,list("")),0) : element(concat(list("")),0)}"


  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.env_name}_${var.ip_configuration_name}"
    #subnet_id                     = "${module.azure_vnet_dtap.subnets_id_single_wan}"
    subnet_id                     = "${element(module.azure_vnet_dtap.subnets_id_wan,count.index)}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "${var.is_static_ip ? "static" : "dynamic"}"
    private_ip_address            = "${var.static_ip}"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.id}"
  }

  tags = "${
    merge(map("Name", format("%s %s %s",var.env_name,var.azure_instance_names, "Public_IP_Interface")),var.global_tags, var.vpc_tags)}"
}
```

And vm code:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "one_volume" {

  count = "${var.single_volume > 0 ? 1 : 0}"
  provider                         = "azurerm.base"
  name                             = "VM_${var.env_name}_${var.azure_instance_names}"
  location                         = "${module.azure_vnet_dtap.resource_group_location}"
  resource_group_name              = "${module.azure_vnet_dtap.resource_group_name}"
  availability_set_id              = "${azurerm_availability_set.availability_set.id}"  
  network_interface_ids            = ["${var.enable_public_ip ? element(concat(azurerm_network_interface.public_ip.*.id,list("")),0) : element(concat(azurerm_network_interface.no_public_ip.*.id,list("")),0)}"]
  vm_size                          = "${var.vm_size}"
  delete_os_disk_on_termination    = "true"
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = "true"
```

All above works fine

Now, i changed output to get rid of Azure subscription

```
output "subnets_id_wan" {

  value = "${slice(split("/",join(",",azurerm_subnet.wan.*.id)), length(split("/",join(",",azurerm_subnet.wan.*.id)))-1, length(split("/",join(",",azurerm_subnet.wan.*.id))))}"
  depends_on = [
    "azurerm_subnet.wan",
  ]
```

output:

```
security_groups_id_wan = [
   DF-DTAP-WAN-Subnet-Security-Group
]
```

when running terraform apply getting:

```
* module.azure_vm.azurerm_virtual_machine.one_volume: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.azure_vm.azurerm_virtual_machine.one_volume: Resource 'azurerm_network_interface.public_ip' does not have attribute 'id' for variable 'azurerm_network_interface.public_ip.*.id'
```

tried this as a test:

```
network_interface_ids            = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.public_ip.*.id,count.index)}"]
```

but same error, if not using slice in output all works fine

Comment: i dont understand, its not complaining about the variable you passed

Comment: azurerm_network_interface.public_ip contains module output variable subnets_id_wan in ip configuration

Comment: I see you just create one network interface, or not. Just use `element(azurerm_network_interface.public_ip.*.id,0)` in the VM code. It will get the only one network interface Id for you.